# Android manager sdk doens't start

Tags: java, android

I have JRE and JDK installed...

```
 /Android/sdk/tools/android ; exit;
/Android/sdk/tools/android: line 84: java: command not found
/Android/sdk/tools/android: line 94: java: command not found
/Android/sdk/tools/android: line 110: exec: java: not found
logout
```

That's a problem with PATH? How did I fix this. Thanks.

Comment: what does you PATH look like?

Comment: Are you using mac or windows? Do you have java path in system path?

Comment: Im using MAC. Here my PATH currently:
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH::/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin/:/usr/java/eclipse/:$PATH

I was trying to fix my PATH from java...

Answer (score 0):

Look's lik, In your Mac JAVA_HOME is not set properly where android normally looking into. Follow this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/), this will guide you to set the JAVA_HOME properly. or otherwise map android sdk to locate JAVA_HOME in your system.